# Proving two sums involving factorials

Tags: combinatorics

How to show that:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k\cdot \frac{a! b! (n-a)!(n-b)!}{n!k!(a-k)!(b-k)!(n+k-a-b)!} \right) &= \frac{ab}n \\
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k^2\cdot \frac{a! b! (n-a)!(n-b)!}{n!k!(a-k)!(b-k)!(n+k-a-b)!} \right) &= \frac{ab}n \cdot \left(1 + \frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{n-1} \right)?
\end{align}

The RHSs are deduced by experimenting a few known $(a,b,n)$, so I can't be sure that these are correct without a proof.

(For simplicity consider $1/(-m)! \equiv 0$ for all negative integers $-m$.)

(The source of the summation is this: suppose we have $n$ cards, exactly $a$ of which are red, exactly $b$ of which are labeled "X", then from the $n!$ possible color-letter combinations, the amount of those having exactly $k$ red-X would be $\frac{a!b!(n-a)!(n-b)!}{k!(a-k)!(b-k)!(n+k-a-b)!}$, then we compute the population mean and variance of the number of red-Xs.)

Comment: As a possible route, I would start by trying induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is straightforward, if I understand the background correctly. You have in effect $n$ cards numbered $1$ through $n$, you choose $b$ of them at random without replacement, you let $Y$ be the number of cards chosen from the subset of cards numbered $1$ through $a$, and you want the expected value of $Y$. For $k=1,\ldots,b$ let $X_k=1$ if the number on the $k$-th card chosen is at most $a$, and let $X_k=0$ otherwise. Then $\Bbb E(X_k)=\frac{a}n$, so by linearity of expectation $$\Bbb E(Y)=\sum_{k=1}^b\frac{a}n=\frac{ab}n\;.$$

**Added:** For the second, $$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\sum_{k=1}^b\operatorname{Var}(X_k)+\sum_{k\ne\ell}\operatorname{Cov}(X_k,X_\ell)\;.$$

Now

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_k)=\Bbb E(X_k^2)-(\Bbb E(X_k))^2=\Bbb E(X_k)-(\Bbb E(X_k))^2=\frac{a}n-\left(\frac{a}n\right)^2\;,$$

and

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_k,X_\ell)=\Bbb E(X_kX_\ell)-\Bbb E(X_k)\Bbb E(X_\ell)=\frac{a(a-1)}{n(n-1)}-\left(\frac{a}n\right)^2\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(Y)&=\frac{ab}n\left(1-\frac{a}n\right)+b(b-1)\left(\frac{a(a-1)}{n(n-1)}-\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{ab}n\left(1-\frac{a}n+\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{n-1}-\frac{a(b-1)}n\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb E(Y^2)&=\operatorname{Var}(Y)+(\Bbb E(Y))^2\\\\
&=\frac{ab}n\left(1-\frac{a}n+\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{n-1}-\frac{a(b-1)}n\right)+\left(\frac{ab}n\right)^2\\\\
&=\frac{ab}n\left(1+\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{n-1}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$